# How to set the default encoding in a buildout script, or during virtualenv creation?

Tags: encoding, plone, buildout

I have a Plone project which is created by a `buildout` script and needs a default encoding of `utf-8`.  This is usually done in the `sitecustomize.py` file of the Python installation.  Since there is a `virtualenv`, I'd like to generate this file automatically, to contain something like:

```py
import sys
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
```

After generation I have two empty `sitecustomize.py` files  - one in `parts/instance/`, and one in `parts/buildout`; but none of these seems to be used (I couldn't find them in `sys.path`).

I tried `zopepy`:

```
>>> from os.path import join, isfile
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> import sys
>>> pprint([p for p in sys.path
...         if isfile(join(p, 'sitecustomize.py'))
...         ])
```

and found another one in my local `lib/python2.7/site-packages/` directory which looks good; but it doesn't work:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.getdefaultencoding()
'ascii'
```

This directory sits near the end of the `sys.path`, because I needed to add it by an `extra-paths` entry (to get another historical package).

Any pointers? Thank you!

**System information**: CentOS 7, Python 2.7.5

**Edit**:
I deleted them two empty `sitecustomize.py` files; now I have a default encoding of `utf-8` in the `zopepy` session but still `ascii` in Plone; this surprises me, because I have in my buildout script:

```
[zopepy]
recipe=zc.recipe.egg
eggs = ${instance:eggs}
extra-paths = ${instance:extra-paths}
interpreter = zopepy
scripts = zopepy
```

To debug this, I created a little function which I added to my code, and which displays a little information about relevant modules in the `sys.path`:

```py
import sys
from os.path import join, isdir, isfile

def sitecustomize_info():
    plen = len(sys.path)
    print '-' * 79
    print 'sys.path has %(plen)d entries' % locals()
    for tup in zip(range(1, plen+1), sys.path):
        nr, dname = tup
        if isdir(dname):
            for fname in ('site.py', 'sitecustomize.py'):
                if isfile(join(dname, fname)):
                    print '%(nr)4d. %(dname)s/%(fname)s' % locals()
            spname = join(dname, 'site-packages', 'sitecustomize.py')
            if isfile(spname):
                print '%(nr)4d. %(spname)s' % locals()
        else:
            print  '?     %(dname)s is not a directory' % locals()
    print '-' * 79
```

Output:

```
sys.path has 303 entries
   8. /usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
 295. /opt/zope/instances/wnzkb/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
?     /usr/lib64/python27.zip is not a directory
 298. /usr/lib64/python2.7/site.py
?     /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk is not a directory
?     /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old is not a directory
 303. /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sitecustomize.py
```

All `sitecustomize.py` files look the same (switching to `utf-8`), and I didn't tweak `site.py` (for now; if everything else fails, I might need to.)

Comment: You should **never** use `sys.setdefaultencoding()`. Using that method is like taking pain killers to cope with blows to the face. Avoid getting hit in the face instead and handle Unicode correctly.

Comment: I agree with Martijn. Let's back this up. What problem led you to believe you wanted to fiddle with the default encoding? There will be a better way to fix it.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't help me. I have a big Plone product I didn't set up from scratch myself, and it used to work well with the default encoding set to `utf-8`; now I need to transfer it to a new server, and I'd like to do it as cleanly and state-of-the-art as possible. But I certainly won't apply unnecessary changes because someone says "`setdefaultencoding` is bad" without telling my why; so I can't judge whether the reasons are valid for my case as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you **really** want/need to use the `sitecustomize.py` trick, you could include this part in your buildout:

```
[fixencode]
recipe = plone.recipe.command
stop-on-error = yes
update-command = ${fixencode:command}
command =
    SITE_PACKAGES=$(${buildout:executable} -c \
      'from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib;print(get_python_lib())')
    cat >  $SITE_PACKAGES/../sitecustomize.py << EOF
    #!${buildout:executable} -S
    import sys
    sys.setdefaultencoding('utf-8')
    EOF
```

It will be added into the site-packages folder from your virtualenv.

Comment: +1 for trying to help me :-)  I tried the `from distutils ...` code in a `zopepy` session, and it gave me `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages` which is not what I want; but perhaps it is possible to use my `sed` command and create a modified local version of `site.py` ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `sitecustomize.py` is not found anymore unless placed in the global `lib` directories ([Discussion "deleting setdefaultencoding in site.py is evil" (2009)](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/106134), [Tracker ticket "sitecustomize.py not found"](http://bugs.python.org/issue1734860)) - and this was made on purpose (!).

This is to prevent users from overriding the default encoding which *might* have been adjusted by some library.  Libraries shouldn't do that, however.

Thus, whoever needs to set the default encoding is seduced to do it globally, which looks like a very silly idea to me. I'd consider it much more reasonable to set this in my *virtual env*ironment.

Unfortunately the `sitecustomize.py` modules in a virtualenv seem to be silently ignored; but it is possible to edit the local `site.py`.  Here is a little `sed` script:

```
#                     vv-------1------vv vv---2---vv vv--------3------vv vv-----------4------------vv
sed --in-place -e 's,^\(    encoding =\) \("ascii"\) \(# Default value\) \(set by _PyUnicode_Init()\),\1 "utf-8" \3 \2 \4,' lib/python2.7/site.py
```